# What part-of-speech is "all" in these sentences?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, pronouns, parts-of-speech

These different dictionarys don't agree about what part-of-speech "all" is when it goes between subject and verb:

For Cambridge dictionary is an adverb

- The kids all go to school on the same bus. [link](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/gramatica/gramatica-britanica/quantifiers/all)

For Macmillan dictionary is a pronoun

- These buildings all belong to the college. [link](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/all_1)

For Merrian-Webster dictionary is an adjective

- They all came late.
- We all need to work faster. [link](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/all)

I am a little confused about them. Can some of you explain them?
Thanks for your answers

Comment: The word *fire* can be a verb or a noun, depending on how it's used. The construction of the sentence around it determines its grammatical function. Why do you think that *all* can't have similar grammatical functions? Why can't it be an adverb, a pronoun, or an adjective, depending on specific context?

Comment: In fact, your question seems disingenuous. Merriam-Webster does *not* say that [*all*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/all) is only an adjective. It clearly gives definitions for all three grammatical functions. (The other dictionaries also give multiple definitions.) The fact that it goes between a subject and verb is insufficient to determine a single function.

Answer (score 2):

This has come up before here. "All" in these examples is a floated quantifier, produced by the transformation "Quantifier Float".  However, if you think that this rule functions to convert a quantifier into an adverb, then it is also reasonable to classify it as an adverb.  McCawley discusses this in [Syntactic Phen.](https://books.google.com/books?id=k6-C5AWWqjQC&q=float#v=snippet&q=float&f=false) and argues that the special case of "all" after a pronoun is from a different rule: Quantifier Pronoun Flip.

Comment: You can also float *both* and *each* in the same way, but perhaps not every such quantifier.